# Induction Implies Well Ordering

Tags: elementary-number-theory, axioms

Every proof that induction implies well ordering I have seen goes: assume $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ has no least element and let $T$ be its complement with respect to $\mathbb{N}$. Since $1$ is the smallest natural number, $1\not\in S$, so $1\in T$. If $1, 2, ..., n\in T$, then $n+1\in T$ since $1, 2, ..., n$ are the only natural numbers smaller than $n+1$. By induction, $T=\mathbb{N}$, so $S$ is empty.

Why is $1$ the smallest natural number? Is it assumed? I know well ordering implies that $1$ is the smallest natural number: if the set $S$ of all natural numbers less than $1$ is nonempty, it has a least element $x$. $x<1$, so $x^2<x$. $x^2\in\mathbb{N}$ since $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under multiplication, contradicting the minimality of $x$.

The axioms I am used to working with are: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring under addition and multiplication, $\mathbb{N}$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ closed under addition and multiplication, trichotomy, and well ordering. I think you also need that negative times negative is positive and negative times positive is negative. If you swap induction for well ordering, can you prove that $1$ is the smallest natural number or prove well ordering a different way?

Comment: (There are two compenting notions of *natural number*. As far as I’m concerned, $0$ is the smallest natural number; $1$ is the smallest positive integer.) The appropriate setting here is the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). From them one can define $\le$ and show that $0$ is the least element of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I think this link answers your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction (more specifically the part about the axoim of choice)

Comment: The Peano axioms work. Is it possible using my axioms?

Comment: @Andrew: Exactly how is $\Bbb N$ defined for you? There are many well-ordered subsets of $\Bbb Z$ that are closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: I believe trichotomy forces $\mathbb{N}$ to be the natural numbers.

Comment: I think you can answer your own question if you define/provide the definition of the partial order you're considering on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: $a>b$ if and only if there exists $c\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a=b+c$.

Comment: @Andrew: Trichotomy merely says that for any $x$ and $y$ exactly one of $x<y$, $x=y$, and $y<x$ holds, so it doesn’t restrict $\Bbb N$ in any way.

Comment: @AndrewBai And how do you define $+$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I meant for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, exactly one of the following is true: $-a\in\mathbb{N}$, $a=0$, or $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @GitGud Commutative and multiplication distributes over it.

Comment: I may also need to stipulate that $\mathbb{Z}$ has no zero divisors.